# Backups Best Practice for SQL Server IaaS

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-backups, backup-strategies

What is considered best practice for SQL backups for SQL Servers (specifically 2017) running in an Azure VM?

I'm aware of:

- Normal SQL Backups to Local Disks
- Azure Backup
- Backup to URL
- VM Snapshots

What I'm considering is:

- Running an Azure Virtual Machine Backup to protect the running virtual machine, enabling me to restore the complete machine if it was lost.
- Backup SQL Server using Azure Backup, for a true SQL Server backup with log protection/truncation enabling me to keep individual database backups for weeks/months.

What I'm concerned about is the size of that VM Backup in that is going to grow and grow every time, but curious as to if the VM was to have problems, how I would get it back online quickly.

What's the best approach here.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-backup-for-sql-server-in-azure-virtual-machines-now-generally-available/

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan, but that doesn't help if the actual VM itself gets corrupted.  The RTO objective would then be hit badly. That article only solves RPO.